# How can i trigger left arrow key event with python (3.9.1)

Tags: python

I am attempting to make a code that automaticly fills in a google sheet and every time i get an error that says that "left" "left arrow" and so on is not a command, here is my code:

```
   from pynput.keyboard import Key,Controller
import random
keyboard= Controller()
x=0
left="left"
while True:
    rando = random.randint(1, 26)
    if rando==1:
        keyboard.press("a")
    if rando==2:
        keyboard.press("b")
    if rando==3:
        keyboard.press("c")
    if rando==4:
        keyboard.press("d")
    if rando==5:
        keyboard.press("e")
    if rando==6:
        keyboard.press("f")
    if rando==7:
        keyboard.press("g")
    if rando==8:
        keyboard.press("h")
    if rando==9:
        keyboard.press("i")
    if rando==10:
        keyboard.press("j")
    if rando==11:
        keyboard.press("k")
    if rando==12:
        keyboard.press("l")
    if rando==13:
        keyboard.press("m")
    if rando==14:
        keyboard.press("n")
    if rando==15:
        keyboard.press("o")
    if rando==16:
        keyboard.press("p")
    if rando==17:
        keyboard.press("q")
    if rando==18:
        keyboard.press("r")
    if rando==19:
        keyboard.press("s")
    if rando==20:
        keyboard.press("t")
    if rando==21:
        keyboard.press("u")
    if rando==22:
        keyboard.press("v")
    if rando==23:
        keyboard.press("w")
    if rando==24:
        keyboard.press("x")
    if rando==25:
        keyboard.press("y")
    if rando==26:
        keyboard.press("z")
    if x==26:
        keyboard.press("up")
    keyboard.press("Left")
```

i am always getting an error for this bottom command
am I doing something wrong with the whole code or is "left" incorrect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the official project page](https://pypi.org/project/pynput/)

> ```
> keyboard.press(Key.space)
> ```

You need to pass a constant from the `Key` enum, not a string.

Comment: How do i mark the question as answered? and thanks

Comment: No problem! There should be a little green checkmark underneath the answer. If you think I answered your question, hit the checkmark and it'll show it as answered.